# box in a box with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a newbie in CSS, trying to create a call to action, in the center of a wordpress page.

I have taken some styles from the rest of the page.

I have troubles in making a box inside a box. The second one should be in my idea in the right part of the big one with different colors for text and backgrounds.

With my attempts (see below) I'm not able to position the second one on the right.

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="margin: 20px 0px; padding: 15px; background: #A5E5EF none repeat  scroll 0% 0%; 
    border-radius: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: ProximaNova-Regular; 
    line-height: 26px; 
    font-size: 21px; color: #3D5B65; text-transform:uppercase;">
    xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
    <div style="position:relative;right:10px;width: 30%;font-family: ProximaNova-Bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 19px;background: #FFF;border-radius: 10px;margin: 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;">CONTACT US

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

**Is that something you are looking for? please let me know if you have some other issue.**

```html
<div style="text-align:center; margin: 20px 0px; padding: 15px; background: #A5E5EF none repeat  scroll 0% 0%; border-radius: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: ProximaNova-Regular; 
line-height: 26px; font-size: 21px; color: #3D5B65; text-transform:uppercase;">
<div style="float:left; width:70%">
 xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
   </div>
<div style="float:right;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; width:25%;
color: #FFF;font-size: 19px; background: #FFF;border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;">CONTACT US

   </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `right:10px;`, the position of this element should be absolute or fixe. Also, you write `width:30%;` which always need to be inside a div with specified width. Try this code below:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div style="margin: 20px 0px; padding: 15px; background: #A5E5EF none repeat  scroll 0% 0%; 
border-radius: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: ProximaNova-Regular; 
line-height: 26px; width:100%;
font-size: 21px; color: #3D5B65; text-transform:uppercase;">
 xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
<div style="position:absolute;right:10px;width: 30%;font-family: ProximaNova-Bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 19px;background: #FFF;border-radius: 10px;margin: 5px 5px;
padding: 5px;">CONTACT US

   </div>

   </div>

 </div>
```

If it doesn't works like you want, let's look into the float position http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi here the trick to make your button to the right. I'm using float to make it your contact div to the right. I already comment some of it, In case you don't understand. Kindly check the demo thanks!.

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="parent1" style="margin: 20px 0px; padding: 15px; background: #A5E5EF none repeat  scroll 0% 0%; 
border-radius: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: ProximaNova-Regular; 
line-height: 26px; 
font-size: 21px; color: #3D5B65; text-transform:uppercase; padding-bottom:20px;"> <!-- I add padding bottom:20px to increase the parent div -->
 xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
<div class="child" style="position:relative;right:10px;width: 30%;font-family: ProximaNova-Bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 19px;background: #FFF;border-radius: 10px;margin: 5px 5px;
padding: 5px;">CONTACT US

   </div>

   </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.child{ /*  I set it to the right using float */
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4k6jLhj/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.callout_box {
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #A5E5EF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: ProximaNova-Regular;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #3D5B65;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  font-family: ProximaNova-Bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout_box">
  <div class="content">
    xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
    <div class="button">
      CONTACT US
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Add `display:inline-block;` to the button and the content. And use classes and style.css. Don't use inline styling.

You can use fixed widths as well. This is better than floating the button imo.

```css
.callout_box {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #A5E5EF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.content {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: ProximaNova-Regular;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #3D5B65;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  font-family: ProximaNova-Bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 19px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout_box">
  <div class="content">
    xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    CONTACT US
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `div` with `overflow: hidden` as a containing div.
And other divs which float inside the container:

```css
    .container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
             Left box
        </div>
        <div class="right">
             Right box
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Box inside Box</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
<div style="margin: 20px 0px; padding: 15px; background: #A5E5EF none repeat  scroll 0% 0%; 
border-radius: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-family: ProximaNova-Regular; 
line-height: 26px; 
font-size: 21px; color: #3D5B65; text-transform:uppercase;">
 xxx xx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx
<div style="position:relative;right:10px;width: 30%;font-family: ProximaNova-Bold; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; color: #FFF; font-size: 19px;background: #FFF;border-radius: 10px;margin: -6px; float:right; padding: 5px;">CONTACT US</div>

   </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```